# Use MIN.JS when Release or else .js for Debug

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

Folks, It could be fairly easy but I could not find easy solution so far.

I've 20-30 java script files that I want such that when the project is in release mode then it uses *.min.js otherwise use .js for debugging purpose.

How can it be done for all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a tool like Squishit to compress your JS/CSS and also configure CDN's.

http://www.codethinked.com/squishit-the-friendly-aspnet-javascript-and-css-squisher

Comment: wow! i have been trying with Yahoo UI compression but I did not knew about Squish is something is all I need it. YOu did sent me back the answer so fast !!!! you are the **star**.